# PHP "if 'any' of these options are set, show it

Tags: php

So I'm using WordPress for this project, and I'm not quite sure how to go about this **neat & clean**.

I've got 8 options total. If ANY of them are set, I need **something** to happen. I also need to execute it for each one set.

Let's use two, for now

```
if( (genesis_get_option('setting_one', 'settings') || genesis_get_option('setting_two', 'settings')) !== '')
    { // print() each one that is set }
```

You can see how doing it that way for 8 options would get very ugly very quickly. All of my settings all have an identical prefix: (`setting_a`, `setting_b`, `setting_one`,`setting_two`)

I was *thinking* something like

```
$settings = array_fill(1, 8, 'setting_');
$labels = array(1 => 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
```

.... but then I don't know where to go from there.

There's GOT to be some sort of clean way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the code for `genesis_get_option`? Maybe you could use the return value to it's advantage and maybe put it through a `switch-case`

Comment: You could just loop over `$labels` to test each one. I doubt you'll get much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat neater way would be:

```
$settings = array("setting_one","setting_two","setting_a");
$has_setting = false;
foreach($settings as $setting){
    if(genesis_get_option($setting, 'settings') !== ''){
        $has_setting = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($has_setting){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Even better would be putting the check into a method to keep the code neater.

Edit: Just realised you need an action for each setting. In that case you can do it inside the loop.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for actually, something a bit neater than what I had while still functioning through a loop, thanks! I'll accept it in 5 when it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(false !== array_search(true,
  array_map(
    'genesis_get_option',
    array('setting_one', 'setting_to' /* ... */ ),
    array('value_one', 'value_two' /* ... */)
  )
)) { /* ... */ }
```